# How to compare data of two CSV files in java (row by row)

Tags: java

I am working on a java project where i have to compare two CSV files. First program should read the data form every column and compare it with all other column's.

CSVFILE1 has 3 column's

```
name , organization , preference
```

CSVFILE2 has 3 column's

```
name , organization , preference .
```

If both file has same values in all the 3 of the column's then program should return true . If not I have to check in 3rd column and make changes to CSVFILE2 .

Presently I have made method where I can read CSVFILE'S and assign to an array. Below is my code.

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hospetal {
    static String file1Path1 = "C:\\\\Users\\\\DANGER\\\\Desktop\\\\New folder\\\\Diva.csv";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ReadFirstFile();

    }

    //Reading file form csv
    public static void ReadFirstFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
        String token1 = "";
        Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File(file1Path1)).useDelimiter(",\\s*");
        ArrayList<String> temps = new ArrayList<String>();

        // while loop
        while (inFile1.hasNext()) {
            // find next line
            token1 = inFile1.next();
            temps.add(token1);
        }

        inFile1.close();

        String[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new String[0]);

        for (String s : tempsArray) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is probably what you are looking for https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/

You can basically read and compare two different excels. I used this library before to read one excel and process row by row

Comment: Thanks for the resource. i will try the solution and let you know.

Comment: what is the change you need to do if they don't match?

Comment: will consider the preference column (preference column start with 1 and increments if not match on first pref) . if the preference is not 1 then will increment and search for 2 (this should meet the criteria where name and organisation should be same ) .

Comment: If you are still intent upon doing this yourself instead of using third party arrays you could put the data into a 2 dimensional arrays where the outer arrays are the rows and the inner arrays are the columns in each row. Then you could iterate over them and do what you need to if something is different

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you take a look at the apache commons-csv library which makes it very easy to read and parse csv records. 
then you can easily parse both files resulting in two lists of CSVRecords which then can be easily compared and in case in case of an a record not being the same in file 2 as in file 1 you can then make changes to it.

edit: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Comment: is there way where i can solve the problem without any 3rd party libraries?

Comment: sure there is. you could always read each file line by line or column by colum into a list and compare them using a comparator and then make changes to the second file where it is required. however why do all the nasty work that someone else has already done and offers it to use for free.